# differences between Infragistics windows forms controls of 13.1 version to Infragistics windows forms controls of 10.3 version

Tags: version

What are the differences between Infragistics windows forms controls of 13.1 version to Infragistics windows forms controls of 10.3 version.

Thanks and Regards,
Ashok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you could find the "What's New in 2013 Volume 1" - http://help.infragistics.com/doc/WinForms/2013.1/CLR4.0/?page=Win_Whats_New.html

In the "Revision History" section, you could find out all of the major improvements in each volume release between 2010 vol.3 and 2013 vol.1

Thanks.